# Issues calling super method in ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

trying to convert ObjectMapper syntax to Swift 3.0:

```
class CustomJsonResponse: Mappable {

    var status: String?
    var response: String?
    var errorCode: CustomErrorCode?

    init() {

    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        status <- map["status"]
        response <- map["response"]
        errorCode <- (map["error_code"], CustomErrorCodeTransform())
    }
}

class CustomChallengesResponse: CustomJsonResponse {

    var challenges: [CustomChallenge]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        super.init(map: map)
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)

        challenges <- map["data.questions"]
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at:

```
required init?(_ map: Map) {
            super.init(map: map)
        }
```

***"Required intializer must be provided by subclass of CustomJsonResponse"***

What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is Map, is it model object??
If so did you implement any init method to that??

Comment: What's the version of ObjectMapper? You getting compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: @wint version 2,0. Compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing:

```
init() {
    super.init()
}
```